# Is it possible to have 3 delimiters for the explode function

Tags: php, split, explode

**Option 1 (spaces)**

```
keyword keyword keyword
```

**Option 2 (line breaks)**

```
keyword
keyword
keyword
```

**Option 3 (commas)**

```
keyword, keyword, keyword
```

Or would I have to use the split function instead? And if so, how?

Comment: nope, you need to use something like `preg_split`, as `split` is actually deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/preg_split) but notice that this will explode on all of your examples at once.

```
$parts = preg_split("/[ ,\n]/", $string);
```

**Edit:** For the third example you give you'll get empty array elements as it's being split on both the comma and the space. Pass `$parts` through [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/array_filter) to strip these out.

Comment: `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` will ignore empty pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Not as simple as preg_split, but [strtok()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) is also an option

Answer (score 0):

## [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) for the win!

This task does not require variable delimiters or regex - assuming all of these "keywords" are "words"...

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0907db852120b6b146623f65cf36ec791972aa7))

```
$strings=[
    'keyword keyword keyword',
    'keyword
keyword
keyword',
    'keyword, keyword, keyword'
];
foreach($strings as $string){
    var_export(str_word_count($string,1));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'keyword',
  1 => 'keyword',
  2 => 'keyword',
)
array (
  0 => 'keyword',
  1 => 'keyword',
  2 => 'keyword',
)
array (
  0 => 'keyword',
  1 => 'keyword',
  2 => 'keyword',
)
```